# Unable to find the file kept inside project

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream

I have an excel file which I have kept in a subfolder of my main package.
I want to read that file. When I read it using `InputStream`, it file is easily detected but when I read using `FileInputStram` or `File file = new File(filepath)` I get the error that the file is not found.

Can anyone help me in reading the file using `FileInputStram` or `File file = new File(filepath)`?

The code what I wrote to read the file is

```
File file = new File("upgradeworkbench/Resources/workbookOut.xlsm");
```

and

```
FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("upgradeworkbench/Resources/workbookOut.xlsm");
```

I tried with `/` in the beginning of the path but still it didn't work.

Comment: Its a web or Simple Java Project?

Comment: Its a simple java project. But I need to run the same code using jar also. So to read files inside the jar I have to keep the files inside a package.

Comment: try ./ in the beginning.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Its not working.

Comment: Print the absolute file path using System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); and copy paste the path in file explorer. Check whether the file path is correct. If not, correct the file path.

Comment: I am running this code using netbeans, which is running a jar instead. the command 'file.getAbsolutePath()` is pointing towards that jar(showing the path of the jar). What shall I do to get the correct path of the file

Comment: use ./ in the beginning and keep your jar file in a folder then create these folder  **"upgradeworkbench/Resources/"** and put you file inside it.Then it should work.

Comment: @AnuragSharma No.. it still didnt work. I want to have a universal jar that can be used by anyone on any system. So I dont want to make any extra folders that has to be their with the jar. I tried every possible way disscused.. but nothing seems to detect the file :(  File path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `File` class you need to provide either absolute or relative path. Absolute path is the full file path e.g. `C:\workbookOut.xlsm`

In relative paths, there is a concept of a `working directory` and it's represented by a . (dot) and everything else is relative to it.

Try either giving the full path or the relative path.

```
File file = new File("./upgradeworkbench/Resources/workbookOut.xlsm");
```

Comment: It is still not working. Still the same exception :(

Comment: what's the operating system you're using?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct for the working dir and upgradeworkbench is not actually your project name.
Try ./Resources/workbookOut.xlsm

Comment: you're probably doing it wrong:

File curdir = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(curdir .getAbsolutePath());

get absoulute path from working dir and follow the relative path from there

Comment: I am running this code using netbeans, which is running a jar instead. the command 'file.getAbsolutePath()` is pointing towards that jar.(showing the path of the jar). What shall I do to get the correct path of the file

Answer (score 0):

If your file in classpath then try below code

```
package mypack;

import java.io.*;

public class TestPath
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream stream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/workbookOut.xlsm");
        System.out.println(stream != null);
        stream = Test.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("workbookOut.xlsm");
        System.out.println(stream != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `InputStream`. I want to work with file

Comment: then use `classLoader`

Comment: When the file exists in a JAR you can't get the file easily. You can access it only as a resource. If you still want to work on a FILE(I don't see why), make a copy of it into a temp file and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file in same package then use the below line it will work

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("workbookOut.xlsm");

File file =new File(url.getPath());
```

Comment: my file is in diiferent package then my class.

Comment: ok, then just use URL url = getClass().getResource("./workbookOut.xlsm");  add dots before slash depend upon the file location.